# Is there an Android app that can use the GPS to track my location, distance, and time traveled on a map?

Tags: gps, maps, gps-tracking

I have a few use cases for this - running or walking to track distance and time, hiking to know if I'm backtracking on myself, and driving aimlessly (well, when gas prices are cheaper than they are now) around an area to explore it so I know places that I've already been.

I did a quick look around the market and nothing stood out. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've used [My Tracks](http://mytracks.appspot.com/) while walking, and a cyclist friend of mine is fond of Sports Track Live

Comment: Looks pretty much like what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've been using it for about 2 weeks now and haven't looked back. Thanks Brett.

Comment: My Tracks is ok, but not great.  It doesn't have offline maps and often doesn't record when you tell it to record, or records when you didn't want it to, and loses the track. :(

Answer (score 6):

I am using [Runkeeper](http://runkeeper.com/) for recording my sport activities.

Comment: It looks like a solid application, but I think MyTracks might be closer to what I'm looking for, so I'm checking that out first.

Answer (score 1):

I am using free version of [Endomondo](http://www.endomondo.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [GPS Logger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mendhak.gpslogger) for this purpose.

EDIT: GPS Logger is a free app for recording GPS Data. You can log in KML/GPX, upload directly to Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: A summary would be nice including the price (if any), just a linky on its own is not sufficient enough to warrant an answer or this could rather be a comment?

Comment: Summary added, but i think everything can be red under the link.

Comment: @Kevin: Answer should be self-contained. Answers that require the reader to go elsewhere in order to glean any useful information are incomplete.